# ng-repeat с Select и отключение уже использующихся options

Tags: angularjs

есть массив:

```
vm.helpersIterator = [ ] //здесь сохраняются наши `<select>` -и
```

есть обьект:

```
vm.helpersObj = {
    2014: {name: 'test', selected: true},  
    1290: {name: 'test1', selected: false},
}
```

и html:

```
<select name="helper" class="form-control"
   ng-repeat="helper in vm.helpersIterator track by $index">
     <option value="">- Select helper -</option>
     <option ng-repeat="(uid, helper) in vm.helpersObj"
             ng-value="uid"
             ng-selected="helper.selected">
             {{helper.name}}
      </option>
</select>
```

надо сделать так, чтоб при добавлении нового `<select>` -а в helpersIterator, в нем используемые `helper`-ы были отключены.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы можете перевести данный вам ответ и добавить сюда

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на этот вопрос был [отвечен](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34733574/ng-repeat-select-with-disabled-options). Надо было с помошью $index соединить 2 массива